# webpack not allowing basic link to stylesheet

Tags: webpack

I downloaded some [boilerplate](https://github.com/wesbos/Learn-Redux-Starter-Files) that uses stylus, babel, webpack, and es6. I want to use a basic link in my index.html to a stylesheet (style.css) but it's not working. I was thinking that something in webpack loader is blocking it so I commented out the below, but it's still not connecting to my basic style.css.

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './client/pokeapp'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
    // js
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['babel'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'client')
    }
    // CSS
    // {
    //   test: /\.styl$/,
    //   include: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
    //   loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader'
    // }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Webpack style-loader, css-loader don't block anything. css-loader is use for resolving imports and url in css files. Style-loader Adds CSS to the DOM by injecting a <style> tag.

Comment: so besides a grammar mistake, where should i look to figure out what my problem is?